# Condition on a coset to be a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ and $a\in G$.
Under what conditions we have that 
the coset 
$$aH=\{ah|h\in H\}$$
is a subgroup of $G$.
I can see that under the conditions that 
$a$ commutes with all elements of $H$ and that $a^2=a$
we have that $aH$ is a subgroup of $G$. Is there any weaker conditions
to have that $aH$ a subgroup of $G$

**Edit** 
I want to show that the inverse of $ah$ which is $h^{-1}a^{-1}$ is still in $aH$ and that the product $ah_1ah_2$ is also in $aH$ for given $h_1$
 and $h_2$ in $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left cosets of a subgroup $H$ form a partition of $G$ and $H$ is one of them. Only one of the sets of this partition contains the identity (wich is necessary for being a group) and that is $H$ itself.

**Edit**:

So left coset $aH$ is only a subgroup if $aH=H$, or equivalently if $a\in H$.

Comment: Are you saying that $aH$ is a subgroup only if $a=1$?

Comment: @palio No, I am saying that $aH$ is only a subgroup if $aH=H$, or equivalently if $a\in H$.

Comment: Thank you very much, i now see it clearly

Answer (score 2):

$aH$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $a \in H$.

For if $aH$ is a subgroup of $G$, we must have $1 \in H$, so $a^{-1} \in H$, thus $a \in H$ since $H$ is a subgroup.

Conversely, if $a \in H$, then $aH = H$, so we conclude that $aH$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @SnowAngel6147 what is wrong with the answer of Ezra? OP asks: *under what condition is the coset $aH$ a subgroup of $G$?* Ezra's answer to this: *iff $a\in H$* is correct.

Comment: sorry. I have some mistake